# How to write time dependent tests Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, mocking

Suppose I have a `function`:

```
def third_day_from_now():
    return datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=3)
```

I want to write tests for this function ? I know that If today is `25th` then the function should return `28`. 
Is there a way somehow I can force the `datetime` object to return `current date` as `25` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`freezegun`](https://github.com/spulec/freezegun) makes mocking datetime very easy.

```
from freezegun import freeze_time

@freeze_time("2015-02-25")
def test_third_day_from_now():
    assert third_day_from_now() == datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 28)
```

Answer (score 1):

Update function to get input date as argument(default value in None)

Then test function by calling with argument i.e. Custom Date and without argument.

**Demo**

```
>>> def third_day_from_now(input_date=None):
...      if input_date:
...           return input_date + datetime.timedelta(days=3)
...      else:
...           return datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=3)
... 

>>> print "Today + 3:", third_day_from_now()
Today + 3: 2015-07-12

>>> input_date = datetime.datetime.strptime('25-05-2015', "%d-%m-%Y").date()
>>> print "Custom Date:", input_date
Custom Date: 2015-05-25
>>> print "Custom Date + 3:", third_day_from_now(input_date)
Custom Date + 3: 2015-05-28
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you wouldn't attempt to alter the system clock, rather you might change the function to something you can test:

```
def third_day_from(someday):
    """Returns the day three days after someday
    :param someday: a datetime to start counting from
    """
    return someday + datetime.timedelta(days=3)

def test_third_day(...)
    today = datetime(25, 5, 2005)
    thirdday = datetime(28, 5, 2005)
    self.assertEqual(third_day_from(today), thirdday)
```